# AWS public DNS removal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created AWS instance with the public IP and the public DNS got attached automatically ec2-xxxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com ,but I don't want public DNS to be showed , So Can we hide that or remove that ,but I want my public IP address attached .
Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: I don't have DNS hostname set for any other VPC's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The automatic DNS hostnames are a VPC setting. You can go to VPC > Your VPCs and right-click on the required VPC. Here you can removed the option to automatically allocate DNS hostnames.

Comment: Hi Michael, why would this solve the wrong problem? The question is resolved. I'm interested in what you think is the problem and how to resolve it.